# Django, i18n, problems with translation after changing LANGUAGE_CODE

Tags: python-3.x, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I have created a multilingual website using Django i18n. But later I needed to change the default language (before LANGUAGE_CODE='ru') to one of those that were in the LANGUAGES configuration setting (now LANGUAGE_CODE='uk').

After that, when the user opens this site and selects the language 'ru', the translation does not work correctly. The models translate correctly, but the templates remain in 'uk'.

At the same time, when the user opens this website and selects the language 'uk' or 'en', the translation works without problems.

Tell me please, what is the reason and how can I solve this problem, or at least where it would be reasonable to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the translation from Russian into Russian was not completed, so the translation from Russian into Ukrainian was taken.

While the default was Russian, no translation was made at all, since there is no translation to this node in the default language. And when it became Ukrainian, in the absence of a translation, translation into Ukrainian began to be used.